How to stop statusbar flashing during OnHScroll of CDialog
I have a CStatusBar at the bottom of my dialog. And during OnSize and OnHScroll I call a function called MoveStatusBar. When it is called from OnSize I pass the value false to stop redrawing.
Function:
void CMyDialog::MoveStatusBar(const bool redrawWindow /*= false*/)
{
    CRect rect;
    GetClientRect(&rect);
    if (m_StatusBar.GetSafeHwnd())
    {
        CRect rctCombo;
        m_cbChairman.GetWindowRect(&rctCombo);
        const int statusBarHeight = rctCombo.Height() + 4;

        m_StatusBar.SetWindowPos(nullptr, 0,
            rect.bottom - statusBarHeight, rect.Width(), statusBarHeight, SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_NOACTIVATE);

        if (redrawWindow)
        {
            m_StatusBar.RedrawWindow(nullptr, nullptr, RDW_INVALIDATE | RDW_UPDATENOW);
        }
    }
}

What I don't understand is that when I horizontally scroll the whole dialog that the dialog has zero flashing and yet the status bar flashes a great deal. Can the flashing be prevented?


I wondered if I should stop invalidating because all the panes are in the same place. But then the status bar has the gripper so it needs to refresh. Catch 22.
